# Batch script: navigation menu with highlighted selection

Tags: windows, user-interface, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I am obsessed with idea of mimicking functionality of 8-bit era programs by virtue of pure command line. So I want to make an array of menu options which can be selected with nominal (since there are no keymap for arrowkeys) left and right keys and confirmed with Enter. To keep things clear there is a working example I wrote. **Please pay attention for ANSI escape codes I use A LOT, not sure if ESC control character would display in browser.**

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Chose and option with [36mZ[0m for left, [36mX[0m for right, [36mC[0m for confirm

:PICKMENU
SETLOCAL
SET menumsg="[7mExit [0m Next"
SET menumsgDef="[7mExit [0m Next"
SET menumsgNxt="[0mExit [7m Next"
:subpick
CHOICE /N /C zxc /m:[3;1H%menumsg%
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO Just in case of errors & GOTO PICKMENU
IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 SET menumsg=%menumsgDef% & GOTO subpick
IF %errorlevel% EQU 2 SET menumsg=%menumsgNxt% & GOTO subpick
IF %errorlevel% EQU 3 GOTO confirm
:confirm
IF %menumsg% EQU %menumsgNxt% (ECHO [0mNext option is chosen & GOTO PICKMENU) ELSE (ECHO ^Exit is chosen! & TIMEOUT 2 >NUL & EXIT)
ENDLOCAL 

PAUSE
```

My problem begins when I try to wrap this menu in some kind of a function, where I could pass arguments instead of making hodgie code every time I need menu or dialog:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM ----So I start with setting variables with idea of argument string tokenisation on the mind----

SET $teststring=OptionOne OptionTwo OptionThree 
SET /A $currentitem=1

REM ----I would use function that I found here on Stackoverflow to count amount of options in my string.----
REM ----This is magic for me, without this solution I would be using FOR loop and delims----

CALL :COUNTOPTIONS %$teststring%

:COUNTOPTIONS
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /A Count=0
:repeatme
IF NOT "%1"=="" (
SET /A Count+=1
SHIFT
GOTO :repeatme
)
ENDLOCAL & SET $optionsamount=%Count%

ECHO The number of words is %$optionsamount%

PAUSE

:PICKCURRENT

REM ----So I got maximum number of options, I guess it would be useful since by design user could stumble upon the
REM ----edge of menu by occasionaly pressing "left" or "right" controls too much. Thats how I limit the variable...

IF %$currentitem% LSS 1 SET /A $currentitem=1
IF %$currentitem% GTR %$optionsamount% SET /A $currentitem=%$optionsamount%
ECHO %$optionsamount%

REM ----This is where I completely lost it. I am trying to echo "options" string as separated items to the target location...-----

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ("%$teststring%") DO ECHO [1;1H%%A

REM ----...and echo "currently selected" item into the same place...

FOR /F "tokens=%$currentitem%" %%B IN ("%$itemstring%") DO SET $selector=[1;1H[7m%%B[0m

REM ----...and make it interactive with choice----

CHOICE /N /C zxc /m:%$selector%
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO oops & GOTO PICKITEM
IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 SET /A "$currentitem=$currentitem-1" & GOTO PICKCURRENT
IF %errorlevel% EQU 2 SET /A "$currentitem=$currentitem+1" & GOTO PICKCURRENT
IF %errorlevel% EQU 3 GOTO confirm

PAUSE
```

(I shoveled script structure in favor of illustrating what am I doing).

Obviously, my problem is in lack of understanding loops and functions, but reading trough reference on ss64 and intense googling were not that enlightening so far. So I would appreciate pointing to education materials as well as comments on my code. I'd like to emphasize that the problem statement doesn't imply usage of additional libraries or resource kits.

Comment: This is on Windows, yes? So how are you getting ANSI escape sequences to have any effect? I've never been able to use them on Windows command line with only native utilities, and your script does not work on my Win 10 machine.

Comment: Yes, I use it on Windows 10 10586. I use to copy escape symbol from any binary opened as a text, alt-code doesn't work for me. My command line code page is 850, UTF-8 and ANSI encoded BAT files works just well. Thank you for pointing me to this issue though, not a good news for my project but useful comment.

Comment: @dbenham Windows 10 added support ANSI escape sequences in the console a few months ago.

Comment: @RossRidge - Oooh! Thanks for the info. I just tried some animations at http://artscene.textfiles.com/vt100/, and they worked. Very cool :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to find solution myself just in few sleepless days:

```
@ECHO OFF
:SELECTLOOP
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /A current=1
:subpick
ECHO ------
SET /A count=0
FOR /F "delims=" %%M IN ("ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE") DO FOR %%N IN (%%M) DO (
SET /A count+=1
SET str!count!=%%N
IF !count! NEQ !current! (ECHO %%N) ELSE (ECHO ^>%%N^<))

CHOICE /N /C zxc /m:"------"
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO error message & GOTO SELECTLOOP
IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 set /A current-=1 & GOTO subcheck
IF %errorlevel% EQU 2 set /A current+=1 & GOTO subcheck 
IF %errorlevel% EQU 3 (ECHO !current! IS CONFIRMED) & (TIMEOUT 3 >NUL)

:subcheck
CLS
IF !current! LSS 1 SET /A current=1
IF !current! GTR !count! SET /A current=!count!
GOTO subpick

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Asking for recommendations for libraries and tutorials is beyond the scope of S.O., and your code was tl;dr for so close to bed time.  Maybe I'll give it another look tomorrow.  The most obvious problem I see is that your functions are located within the main runtime, and you never `goto` past them.  They should be after the final `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` so they aren't executed in the normal top-to-bottom sequence of the batch script.  Example:

```perl
@echo off & setlocal
call :add 5 9 sum
echo The sum is %sum%

exit /b

rem // Functions go here, below exit /b

:add <num1> <num2> <return_var>
set /a %~3=%~1 + %~2
goto :EOF

:subtract <num1> <num2> <return_var>
set /a %~3=%~1 - %~2
goto :EOF
```

---

But I thought at least for now I might share a more complete menu script that doesn't require an ansi interpreter.

```perl
<# : Batch portion
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "menu[0]=Format C:"
set "menu[1]=Send spam to boss"
set "menu[2]=Truncate database *"
set "menu[3]=Randomize user password"
set "menu[4]=Download Dilbert"
set "menu[5]=Hack local AD"

for /L %%I in (6,1,15) do set "menu[%%I]=loop-generated demo item %%I"

set "default=0"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
echo You chose !menu[%ERRORLEVEL%]!.

goto :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

$menutitle = "CHOOSE YOUR WEAPON"
$menuprompt = "Use the arrow keys.  Hit Enter to select."
$menufgc = "yellow"
$menubgc = "darkblue"

[int]$selection = $env:default
$h = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height
$w = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width

# assume the dialog must be at least as wide as the menu prompt
$len = [math]::max($menuprompt.length, $menutitle.length)

# get all environment vars matching menu[int]
$menu = gci env: | ?{ $_.Name -match "^menu\[(\d+)\]$" } | sort @{

    # sort on array index as int
    Expression={[int][RegEx]::Match($_.Name, '\d+').Value}

} | %{
    $val = $_.Value.trim()
    # truncate long values
    if ($val.length -gt ($w - 8)) { $val = $val.Substring(0,($w - 11)) + "..." }
    $val
    # as long as we're looping through all vals anyway, check whether the
    # dialog needs to be widened
    $len = [math]::max($val.Length, $len)
}

# dialog must accomodate string length + box borders + idx label
$dialogwidth = $len + 8

# center horizontally
$xpos = [math]::floor(($w - $dialogwidth) / 2)

# center at top 1/3 of the console
$ypos = [math]::floor(($h - ($menu.Length + 4)) / 3)

# Is the console window scrolled?
$offY = [console]::WindowTop

# top left corner coords...
$x = [math]::max(($xpos - 1), 0); $y = [math]::max(($offY + $ypos - 1), 0)
$coords = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates $x, $y

# ... to the bottom right corner coords
$rect = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle `
    $coords.X, $coords.Y, ($w - $xpos + 1), ($offY + $ypos + $menu.length + 4 + 1)

# The original console contents will be restored later.
$buffer = $Host.UI.RawUI.GetBufferContents($rect)

function destroy { $Host.UI.RawUI.SetBufferContents($coords,$buffer) }

$box = @{
    "nw" = [char]0x2554     # northwest corner
    "ns" = [char]0x2550     # horizontal line
    "ne" = [char]0x2557     # northeast corner
    "ew" = [char]0x2551     # vertical line
    "sw" = [char]0x255A     # southwest corner
    "se" = [char]0x255D     # southeast corner
    "lsel" = [char]0x2192   # right arrow
    "rsel" = [char]0x2190   # left arrow

}

function WriteTo-Pos ([string]$str, [int]$x = 0, [int]$y = 0,
    [string]$bgc = $menubgc, [string]$fgc = $menufgc) {
    $saveY = [console]::CursorTop
    [console]::setcursorposition($x,$offY+$y)
    Write-Host $str -b $bgc -f $fgc -nonewline
    [console]::setcursorposition(0,$saveY)
}

# Wait for keypress of a recognized key, return virtual key code
function getKey {

    # PgUp/PgDn + arrows + enter + 0-9
    $valid = 33..34 + 37..40 + 13 + 48..(47 + [math]::min($menu.length, 10))

    # 10=a, 11=b, etc.
    if ($menu.length -gt 10) { $valid += 65..(54 + $menu.length) }

    while (-not ($valid -contains $keycode)) {
        $keycode = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode
    }
    $keycode
}

# for centering the title and footer prompt
function center([string]$what, [string]$fill = " ") {
    $lpad = $fill * [math]::max([math]::floor(($dialogwidth - 4 - $what.length) / 2), 0)
    $rpad = $fill * [math]::max(($dialogwidth - 4 - $what.length - $lpad.length), 0)
    "$lpad $what $rpad"
}

function menu {
    $y = $ypos
    WriteTo-Pos ($box.nw + (center $menutitle $box.ns) + $box.ne) $xpos ($y++)
    WriteTo-Pos ($box.ew + (" " * ($dialogwidth - 2)) + $box.ew) $xpos ($y++)

    # while $item can equal $menu[$i++] without error...
    for ($i=0; $item = $menu[$i]; $i++) {
        $rtpad = " " * [math]::max(($dialogwidth - 8 - $item.length), 0)
        if ($i -eq $selection) {
            WriteTo-Pos ($box.ew + "  " + $box.lsel + " $item " + $box.rsel + $rtpad `
                + $box.ew) $xpos ($y++) $menufgc $menubgc
        } else {
            # if $i is 2 digits, switch to the alphabet for labeling
            $idx = $i; if ($i -gt 9) { [char]$idx = $i + 55 }
            WriteTo-Pos ($box.ew + " $idx`: $item  $rtpad" + $box.ew) $xpos ($y++)
        }
    }
    WriteTo-Pos ($box.sw + ([string]$box.ns * ($dialogwidth - 2) + $box.se)) $xpos ($y++)
    WriteTo-Pos (" " + (center $menuprompt) + " ") $xpos ($y++)
    1
}

while (menu) {

    [int]$key = getKey

    switch ($key) {

        33 { $selection = 0; break }    # PgUp/PgDn
        34 { $selection = $menu.length - 1; break }

        37 {}   # left or up
        38 { if ($selection) { $selection-- }; break }

        39 {}   # right or down
        40 { if ($selection -lt ($menu.length - 1)) { $selection++ }; break }

        # letter, number, or enter
        default {
            # if alpha key, align with VirtualKeyCodes of number keys
            if ($key -gt 64) { $key -= 7 }
            if ($key -gt 13) {$selection = $key - 48}

            # restore the original console buffer contents
            destroy
            exit($selection)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a example but its very long

```
@echo off
mode con cols=60 lines=20
echo [40m[0m
:optionshight
title                             Menu Choices
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right                          X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                      The Main Menu
echo                                   The Main Menu
echo                                The Main Menu
echo                             The Main Menu
echo   The Main Menu          The Main Menu
echo      The Main Menu    The Main Menu
echo         The Main MenuThe Main Menu
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo [7mOptions[0m Menu Time Info Extras Quit
choice /c adx >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto quithight
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto menuhight
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto options
:quithight
title                             Menu Choices
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right    [30mW = Up[0m                X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                      The Main Menu
echo                                   The Main Menu
echo                                The Main Menu
echo                             The Main Menu
echo   The Main Menu          The Main Menu
echo      The Main Menu    The Main Menu
echo         The Main MenuThe Main Menu
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Options Menu Time Info Extras [7mQuit[0m
choice /c adx >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto extrashight
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto optionshight
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto quit
:menuhight
title                             Menu Choices
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right                          X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                      The Main Menu
echo                                   The Main Menu
echo                                The Main Menu
echo                             The Main Menu
echo   The Main Menu          The Main Menu
echo      The Main Menu    The Main Menu
echo         The Main MenuThe Main Menu
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Options [7mMenu[0m Time Info Extras Quit
choice /c adx >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto optionshight
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto timehight
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto nothinghere1
:timehight
title                             Menu Choices
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right                          X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                      The Main Menu
echo                                   The Main Menu
echo                                The Main Menu
echo                             The Main Menu
echo   The Main Menu          The Main Menu
echo      The Main Menu    The Main Menu
echo         The Main MenuThe Main Menu
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Options Menu [7mTime[0m Info Extras Quit
choice /c adx >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto menuhight
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto infohight
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto time
:time
title                                  Time
cls
echo                                                  X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                           %time%
echo.
echo                    %date%
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo [7mBack[0m
choice /t 1 /c xq /d q>nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto timehight
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto time
goto time
:infohight
title                             Menu Choices
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right                          X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                      The Main Menu
echo                                   The Main Menu
echo                                The Main Menu
echo                             The Main Menu
echo   The Main Menu          The Main Menu
echo      The Main Menu    The Main Menu
echo         The Main MenuThe Main Menu
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Options Menu Time [7mInfo[0m Extras Quit
choice /c adx >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto timehight
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto extrashight
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto infopage1
:extrashight
title                             Menu Choices
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right                          X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                      The Main Menu
echo                                   The Main Menu
echo                                The Main Menu
echo                             The Main Menu
echo   The Main Menu          The Main Menu
echo      The Main Menu    The Main Menu
echo         The Main MenuThe Main Menu
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Options Menu Time Info [7mExtras[0m Quit
choice /c adx >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto infohight
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto quithight
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto extras
:infopage1
title                               Info
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right                          X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo [7mBack[0m
choice /c x >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto infohight
:options
title                             Options
cls
echo                                                  X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                           Turn Back
echo.
echo       Nothing here becuz what need to settings here?
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo [7mBack[0m
choice /c x >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto optionshight
:quit
title                            bye lol
exit
:nothinghere1
title                             Menu
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right    W = Up    S = Down
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo       [7mNothing Here[0m             Nothing Here
echo.
echo.
echo       Nothing Here             Nothing Here
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Back
choice /c wasd >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto nothinghereback
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto nothinghere2
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto nothinghere3
if %errorlevel% EQU 4 goto nothinghere2
:nothinghere2
title                             Menu
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right    W = Up    S = Down
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo       Nothing Here             [7mNothing Here[0m
echo.
echo.
echo       Nothing Here             Nothing Here
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Back
choice /c wasd >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto nothinghereback
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto nothinghere1
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto nothinghere4
if %errorlevel% EQU 4 goto nothinghere1
:nothinghere3
title                             Menu
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right    W = Up    S = Down
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo       Nothing Here             Nothing Here
echo.
echo.
echo       [7mNothing Here[0m             Nothing Here
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Back
choice /c wasd >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto nothinghere1
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto nothinghere4
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto nothinghereback
if %errorlevel% EQU 4 goto nothinghere4
:nothinghere4
title                             Menu
cls
echo   A = Left    D = Right    W = Up    S = Down
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo       Nothing Here             Nothing Here
echo.
echo.
echo       Nothing Here             [7mNothing Here[0m
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo Back
choice /c wasd >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto nothinghere2
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto nothinghere3
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto nothinghereback
if %errorlevel% EQU 4 goto nothinghere3
:nothinghereback
title                             Menu
cls
echo                            W = Up    S = Down    X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo       Nothing Here             Nothing Here
echo.
echo.
echo       Nothing Here             Nothing Here
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo [7mBack[0m
choice /c wsx >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto nothinghere3
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto nothinghere1
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto menuhight
:extras
title                             Menu
cls
echo                                                  X = Select
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo.
echo Quit Button is For Quit :)
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ____________________________________________________________
echo.
echo [7mBack[0m
choice /c x >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto extrashight
```