# Multi Select Menu

Tags: batch-file

### Good day!

Recently I made thread, where I asked, how to create, or is it possible to create Tickmenu in Batch.

One of those who answered was - [Dennis van Gils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5022761/dennis-van-gils), who kindly presented his Multi Select menu.

Here is code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "getKeyMacro=powershell -noprofile "^
    while (-not (37..40+13).contains($x)) {^
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode^
    }^
    if ($x -eq 13) {^
    'enter'^
    }^
    ('left','up','right','down')[$x - 37]^
""

set "num=0"
for %%a in ("7zip"
            "7zip x64"
            "AdobeReader"
            "Far x64"
            "Far x86") do (
   set /A num+=1
   set "option!num!=0"
   set "option!num!name=%%~a"
)
set "maxOptions=%num%"
set "selected=1"
:select
cls
echo use ^<right^> arrow to continue, ^<up^> and ^<down^> to select, and ^<enter^> to toggle
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%maxOptions%) DO (
set "display=[ ]"
if !option%%G! equ 1 set "display=[x]"
if %%G equ !selected! set "display=^>!display!"
echo !display! !option%%Gname!
)
FOR /F "delims==" %%G IN ('%getKeyMacro%') DO set "key=%%G"
if "%key%"=="up" set /a "selected-=1"
if "%key%"=="down" set /a "selected+=1"
if %selected% lss 1 set "selected=1"
if %selected% gtr %maxOptions% set "selected=!%maxOptions%!"
if "%key%"=="enter" goto toggle
if "%key%"=="right" goto OK
goto select

:toggle
set /a "option%selected%+=1"
set /a "option%selected%=!option%selected%!%%2"
goto select

:OK
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%maxOptions%) DO (
if !option%%G! equ 1 (
call :logic "%%G"
)
)
pause

goto :eof
:logic
 set "install=%~1"
 if "%install%"=="1" (
  msiexec /i D:\Install\Software\7z920.msi /quiet /qn 
  echo executing %install%
 )

 if "%install%"=="2" (
  msiexec /i D:\Install\Software\7z920x64.msi /quiet /qn 
  echo executing %install%
 )

 if "%install%"=="3" (
  Start "" "D:\Install\Software\AdbeRdr11010_en_US"
  echo executing %install%
 )

 if "%install%"=="4" (
  msiexec /i "D:\Install\Software\Far x64.msi" /quiet /qn 
  echo executing %install%
 )

 if "%install%"=="5" (
  msiexec /i "D:\Install\Software\Far x86.msi" /quiet /qn 
  echo executing %install%
 )
```

When he posted his code, he noted, that at the :logic, I need to create simple If statements so that script can run programs.

I made those If statements but for some reason script still gives me Unexpected error. I am new at Batch scripting so for me, it's to hard to understand this advenced level code.

So, my question is, Why is this code not working?

Regards,
Vairis

---

> Edit, Ok guys, I think I will need to Ask Dennis himself, since that's
>   his code ^_^. Thank you everyone for your time. I don't know if this
>   thread should be closed since questions is unanswered, but this
>   question might be at bottom of the page at this moment, so I will ask
>   Moderator to close this Thread.

Once again, Thank you guys :)
Regards

Comment: You can get inspired by this code to create a dynamic menu and if you need some assistance to create your own like this one just ask me ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268530/sound-in-batch?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: [Shameless plug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38176284/1683264).

Comment: Thank you, I will definetely use this one day, but not right now. Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommand you using a simple menu like this one from **[DOS Batch - Menus](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsMenu.php)**

---

**Description :**

This simple menu framework parses itself for batch labels of certain signature and lists them as menu items. The self-parsing feature makes the menu generic. New menu items can be inserted by adding new function blocks without changing the menu infrastructure.

---

**Features:**

1. simple and well structured
2. easy to enhance
3. easy to maintain

---

```
@echo off
Title Example of a dynamic menu
Mode con cols=70 lines=13 & color 9E 
:menuLOOP
echo(
echo(    =============================Menu==============================
echo(
for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do echo                        %%A  %%B
echo(
echo(    ===============================================================
set choice=
echo( & set /p choice=Make a choice or hit ENTER to quit: || GOTO :EOF
echo( & call :menu_[%choice%]
GOTO:menuLOOP

:menu_[1] Install 7zip (x86 bits)
cls
set "Install=Install 7zip (x32 bits)"
rem msiexec /i D:\Install\Software\7z920.msi /quiet /qn 
echo Executing %install%
Timeout /T 30 /nobreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP

:menu_[2] Install 7zip (x64 bits)
cls
set "Install=Install 7zip (x64 bits)"
rem msiexec /i D:\Install\Software\7z920x64.msi /quiet /qn 
echo Executing %install%
Timeout /T 30 /nobreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP

:menu_[3] Install Adobe Reader
cls
set "Install=Install Adobe Reader"
rem Start "" "D:\Install\Software\AdbeRdr11010_en_US"
echo Executing %install%
Timeout /T 30 /nobreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP

:menu_[4] Far (x64)
cls
set "Install=Install Far (x64)"
Rem msiexec /i "D:\Install\Software\Far x64.msi" /quiet /qn 
echo Executing %install%
Timeout /T 30 /nobreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP

:menu_[5] Far (x32)
cls
set "Install=Install Far (x32)"
Rem msiexec /i "D:\Install\Software\Far x86.msi" /quiet /qn 
echo Executing %install%
Timeout /T 30 /nobreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
```

Comment: *Give a try* is not an answer. Explain **why** the poster should use this code, and how it works differently than the code in the post. Dumping code and saying *try this* is not an answer here, because it teaches or explains nothing. (Haven't we had this conversation before?)

Comment: You haven't answered the poster's question, however. The poster asked why the code they posted doesn't work. You've ignored that question entirely and suggested totally different code. It's fine to suggest an alternative, but you need to answer the question asked first before doing so.

Comment: Don't need to argue guys, Hackoo, thank you for your code, It might help me out one day, and it looks awesome, but problem is, script that I am trying to make, needs to be Multi Select Menu. 

See, when I am using your code, you can't choose more than 1 program, and this is why exactly I need to fix code that I posted.

But thank you for your time :)